# VMProtect and webclient

Tags: c#, webclient, tls1.2, obfuscation

I have a problem with protecting my soft with VMProtect.

url (with redirect)- no secerity, no SSL/TLS (HTML 1.1, http)
In Visual Studio I have no Errors (compiled, without protection).

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, Agent);
content = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
```

With this code i have an error: The request was aborted. Could not create SSL/TLS connection

I tried to add (before and after new Weblicent()):

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true; 

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };  
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11| SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

Also tried add only this:

`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 (and with Ssl3)`

Not worked: Eset antivirus blocking: MSIL/TrojanDownloader.Agent.LNO